# Does pygbag directly interprets python in the browser or compiles it to wasm and then runs it?

Tags: python, webassembly, pygbag

I was wandering through the docs of pygbag, and I couldn't find how the python scripts are actually executed from the browser.

I made a test project to look how the files created by pygbag looked like, but I couldn't really figure out what role the index.html exactly plays. It seemed to me like I couldn't find any script in it, so I supposed that it could be directly interpreted, but I'm not really sure.

There is a python script in the html file, and I found one line which seems to run the main program : `await shell.runpy(main, callback=ui_callback)`, but I don't know whether it just executes the python script in the folder or if the script is somewhere compiled in this file.

Could anyone explain me ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When running in the webpage pygbag is in fact a C runtime linked to libpython ( cpython-wasm from python.org) compiled to WebAssembly with emscripten compiler and hosted on a CDN (pygame-web.github.io). It is downloaded once per game and per version update for fast local use.

There's some javascript glue to connect the C library used by pygbag and python to some file descriptors. You cannot guess the mechanism that easily because calls originate from wasm cpu which is not exposed in javascript console.

Those file descriptors manipulated by the libc (musl provided by emsdk the portable emscripten compiler) can be in a virtual filesystem hosted by MEMFS from emscripten runtime ( eg for /tmp )  or BrowserFS a more advanced virtual filesystem ( /data and /usr ).

They can also be stdin/stdout/stderr file descriptors and this is why you cannot find the file on startup : the python part of html file is sent to python interpreter as if you typed it in your shell this is done by calling PyRun_InteractiveLoop on that file descriptor.

Later if a file "main.py" is found in the Virtual filesystem it is queued but you can also pass relative file url on the command line eg https://pygame-web.github.io/showroom/pypad.html#src/test_panda3d_cube.py. It also work with github gist raw links. pygbag can also embed code or git repo eg https://pygame-web.github.io/showroom/test_embed_git.html directly in html pages.

Some packages like pygame-ce, Panda3D or Harfang3D are indeed pre-compiled to WebAssembly and that's because they are mostly C or C++.

Python code is actually interpreted and type-annotated code could be compiled direcly to Wasm but that fonctionnality is not (yet) available for public use.

The format choosen for game archive is a zip file similar to android APK though unaligned and unsigned. The android runtime to make these run on real android is not (yet) available for public use either.

Everyone is welcome to add more informations on pygame-web.github.io wiki.

Comment: Thank you very much for your very clear answer !

Answer (score 1):

I think it would be really great if they cleaned up the project or added more docs so that the wasm build process is easier to understand and expand on.

I also looked through the index.html page and tried to do a similar thing to what you are asking about. From what I understand, there’s an Android web assembly file being built out of the python code, then it’s being run in the in the index.html file in like an iFrame or canvas (I apologize, I am not a front end expert).  I believe the pyscript stuff is for communicating to/from the python WASM file.  I do not believe that the pygame itself is being interpreted because it would likely be way way slower and too inefficient to run this way.  I have had no performance issues running a test game I made in the browser.

I personally really appreciate pygbag, and I would love to see it become even easier/better to embed pygame in the browser.  I feel like more docs & contributions would help a lot.  However, I am also a little concerned about the security of this package. I would feel a lot more comfortable contributing and using it if it had a 95+ trust score on package rating sites!

Hope this can help you!

Answer (score 1):

the build.apk file pygbag outputs is a .zip file with python code inside as far as i know